# Unable to Open IFrame in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe

I am trying to open an iframe in my application and its not loading, its giving me a error message like `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`
and logging me out. Cam any one suggest as to what could be the workaround. Thahnks.

This link [Iframe causes Can't Verify CSRF Token Authenticity n Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239818/iframe-causes-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-n-rails) does not answer my question, I have the gem installed my iframe loads correctly, but there is any request that is happening in iframe that time niether p3p headers nor csrf token are sent

Comment: Hello brad, i tried the gem mentioned there but non success

Comment: this has not solved my issue, i need to explain